# TestNG - WebDriver - Web apps Testing - Independent Tests

Tags: java, database, oracle, webdriver, testng

How to handle DB inside of your script using TestNG framework?
How to delete DB before each run of test script?
How to load sql file into clean DB before running test script?

**Goal:** Each test case must be independent
**Framework:** TestNG
**Language:** Java

Each test case must be independent against other test cases. Goal is to run Test cases randomly, no order is required.

Previously I have used PHPUnit framework where each test case was independent.

Before running each test script, I would:

1. dropdatabase
2. create a new database
3. load sql file into database with initial data

I was using this inside of shell script, and I would call shell script via command line:

**mysql -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PWD -h$HOST -e "DROP DATABASE $DB_NAME"**

**mysql -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PWD -h$HOST -e "CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME"**

**mysql -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PWD -h$HOST $DB_NAME < sql/dbinit.sql**

Google-ing was not helpfull, therefore I am posting question here. I would need something like this for TestNG but I have not found anything similiar.

Could someone give advice to fellow QA. 
How do you handle with oracle database, how do you delete data from the DB and load them inside of your test script?

Any advice, book, tutorial would be very helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into DbUnit. I've recently started using it myself (I'm a TestNG user) and, as of yet, I haven't come across scenarios where you absolutely need JUnit itself. You can restore your database between tests, populate it, export it, etc ...

http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/

basic example:

```
private DatabaseHelper dbh;
private EntityManager em;
private IDatabaseConnection connection;
private IDataSet dataset;

@BeforeClass
private void setupDatabaseResource() throws Exception {
    // using JPA and a custom helper class
    em = dbh.getEntityManager();
    connection = new DatabaseConnection(((SessionImpl) (em.getDelegate())).connection());

    connection.getConfig().setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY, new HsqldbDataTypeFactory());

    // full database export
    IDataSet fullDataSet = connection.createDataSet();

    FlatXmlDataSet.write(fullDataSet, new FileOutputStream("target/generated-sources/test-dataset.xml"));

    FlatXmlDataSetBuilder flatXmlDataSetBuilder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();
    flatXmlDataSetBuilder.setColumnSensing(true);

    // keep the dataset in memory, for later restore points
    dataset = flatXmlDataSetBuilder.build(new FileInputStream("target/generated-sources/test-dataset.xml"));
}
```

edit: an example where `@BeforeMethod` restores your database between tests

```
@BeforeMethod
public void cleanDB() throws Exception {
    DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(connection, dataset);
}
```